# Dynamic url_path in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a city page with a jQuery content carousel. The content of the carousel is filed by a each loop.

```
CityController 
    @events = @city.events.find_all_by_hot(true)
    @activities = @city.activities.find_all_by_hot(true)
    @sights = @city.sights.find_all_by_hot(true)
    @hot = @events + @activities + @sights

Class city
   has_many: events
end

class events
   belongs_to :city
   has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable    
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

Activities and sights models are the same

```
City view content slider:
  @hot.each do |a|
  a.attachments.each do |a|
  = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" ), url_path
```

I want to generate links (url_path) in my each loop...how can I realize this? It cannot place the url_path of the routes because they are dymanic based on which attachment (image) is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your syntax of `image_tag` is incorrect you can try this

```
@hot.each do |hot|
  hot.attachments.each do |a|
    link_to polymorphic_path(a.attachable) do
      image_tag(a.file.url, :height => "325px", :width => "650px")
    end
  end
end
```

If I understand your problem correctly. Also check out the [polymorphic_path](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path) helper, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that the link should point to the `a` which can be any of events, activities, sights? as

```
@hot = @events + @activities + @sights
```

I would try creating a special controller action in the CityController

```
   def hottie
     @duck = Kernel.const_get(params[:type]).find_by_id(params[:id])
     redirect_to @duck
   end
```

then add something like

```
  match 'hottie/:type/:id' => 'city#hottie', as: 'hot'
```

which should give you a path helper that you can use as this:

```
<%=link_to("Open", hot_path(a.class.to_s, a.id)) %>
```

Addition: this is of course a bit dirty and needs some security things considered (e.g. limit it to show only special types). You could also consider moving the three classes Event, Activities and Sights into a Object Hierarchy using STI; that should eliminate the need of passing the type in the request.